# How to sync 2 hard drives without being connected to them at the same time?

Tags: data-synchronization, backup, hard-drive

Set-up:

- 1 external hard drive at work
- 1 external hard drive at home
- Macbook that travels between work and home

Hard drive contains iTunes Music Library that I like to have synced between home and work without taking hard drives with me. In 1 direction would be fine. Carbon Copy Cloner over the internet works perfectly but is way too slow.

Is there a method or software available to sync these drives with my Macbook acting as a delta? New files from home are copied to my Macbook and then at work copied from Macbook to external hard drive.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you copy everything onto the MacBook and then transfer everything from the MacBook onto the other hard drive?